# a small doubt regarding html frames

Tags: html

Im designing a static webpage....and itz a sample online bookshoppe webpage... in that i divided the window in to three frames, top left and rite respectively... the top frame consists of the title , the left frame consists of all the categories of books available and the right frame consists of the tabs... Home Registration Catelogue login ... etc and now wen im opening a link for example if i click on registration it is being opened in another window rather than in the same window same frame i.e., right frame... so anyone plz help me how to do it.. What i need to do is.. if i click on any one of the tabs(links which i have mentioned) it should be opened in the same frame... thanks in advance (:

Comment: Could you please try to write properly? It's very hard to read your question. Also: why are you using frames in 2010?

Comment: @Jan Hančič: Write properly in which language?  I'm guessing there's a translation barrier.  "Jothsna" sounds like an Indian name, and while English is common there it is by no means the only language used.  I've seen worse attempts at English even from native speakers of it.  Your point on the use of frames, however, is definitely applicable.  It sounds like a poor design.

Comment: btw, y u use iframe? itz not cool

Comment: @David I agree, I'm not a native English speaker, but at least I try to use commas, periods, etc properly (I'm not saying I'm successful :)). And almost every browser has a spell-checker so you could at least try to correct the misspelled words when posting.

Answer (score 2):

Do the links have `target` attributes that are telling them where to open?  If they do, that's likely the problem.  If they do not, you can [specify a target](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.3).

Comment: @Jothsna Nalla: I'm not worried about your language skills.  I am, however, worried that you are being actively _taught_ to use HTML frames.  Their use is very much considered deprecated in HTML and widely considered to be indicative of bad design.

Comment: the education system is like that.. and moreover they just want us to know all the basics... itz juss a starting...

Comment: Good Question.. I too got the same one... but im helpless!! Itz in the syllabus... so have to do it!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `target="inlineframe"` Example http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/q8CqX/

Comment: ok. did you try add target="inlineframe" to your link? `<a target="inlineframe" href="#">` It's work? Let me know